# listing base DNs using opendj Rest

Tags: ldap, opendj

Is it possible to list all base DNs in OpenDJ using REST?

Ex:

```
I have multiple backends,
backend1:
base DN1:dc=abc,dc=company,dc=com
base DN2:dc=xyz,dc=company,dc=com
backend2:
base DN3: dc=zzz,dc=company,dc=com
```

Answer (score 0):

OpenDJ is an LDAP directory server and you can get all base DNs over LDAP.
The NamingContexts attribute of the RootDSE is meant for that (and is defined in the LDAPv3 specifications).

The REST API is meant to provide access to the data. Future versions of OpenDJ will expose the configuration and monitoring information through a REST API. But there is no intention to provide all LDAP capabilities through the REST API. Typically the list of base DNs, is not available through the REST API and is not on the priority list for future versions either.